# iBeacon, app receiving/transmitting

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Practical question here:

With iBeacon technology by Apple, could you create an app that acts both as a transmitter/receiver. That way users can interact with other nearby users that have the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create an app that both acts as a beacon and scans for beacons. But you would not be able to offer much "interaction" this way. The iBeacons API just tells you when a beacon has come in range; it offers no way for beacons to communicate further. For this your best bet might be Core Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

@jonahb is exactly right -- iBeacons alone will not allow you to do what you want.  However, if you build a web service and add it to the mix, what you suggest becomes possible.  See my proposal [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726087/how-to-send-data-to-an-iphone-which-is-turned-into-a-ibeacon)

Answer (score 0):

To add to what jonahb and davidyoung have said, you could also write an app that uses a combination of iBeacons and lower-level BLE.

You'd use the iBeacons for discovery, and once you find another user running your app, you could either advertise as a BLE peripheral, or listen for advertisements from the other device.

BLE lets you create 2-way links and send/receive data between connected devices, but it's pretty slow, and best for small amounts of data.