# Exchange data with near by Beacon securly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

Currently I am having this situation, I have 3 iOS device and one of the device act as Central & rest 2 are acting as peripheral.[image]

Also my central can able to scan and populate these two device `UUID`, `Major ID`, `Minor ID` & their proximity in a table view.

1. Now when I tap on any particular cell I want to exchange some data from my central to that particular device(also vice versa).How to achieve this ?
2. Is there any way available So that I can get the device name (Tom's iPhone, Sam's iPad etc.) along with `UUID`, `Major ID`, `Minor ID` & their proximity ?
3. Is there any way available to make these data exchange secure, So no one can snoop these data ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by combining iBeacons with web services running over HTTPS to ensure they are secure.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739097/1461050).

Getting data like "device name" can be accomplished with off the shelf services like my company's [ProximityKit](http://proximitykit.com).

It is true that iBeacons cannot do these things by themselves, but it is important to remember they are just a small building block that must be combined with other tools to make more complex systems.

The functionality you suggest might also be accomplished by using a secondary Bluetooth channel for data transfer, but this would require you building custom hardware for your device shown on the left of your diagram, since standard iBeacons do not exchange data.

Answer (score 1):

iBeacons are not designed to transmit data.
You can use iBeacons for detection of devices, and then set up a MultiPeerSession to transmit data. Checkout the MultiPeerConnectivity framework. There is also an excellent WWDC 2013 session on it.
The MCSession object supports encryption and authentication challenging (e.g. using certificates).

Answer (score 0):

The iBeacon protocol doesn't allow for any sort of transmission back to a beacon. If you're using multiple iOS devices, wish to locate nearby devices and transmit data, I suggest you instead look at Apple's [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework. There's a good introduction about it on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/).

> Multipeer Connectivity is a framework that enables nearby devices to communicate over infrastructure Wi-Fi networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and **Bluetooth** personal area networks. Connected peers are able **securely transmit messages**, streams, or file resources to other devices without going through an intermediary web service.